# Ruby equivalent to PHP's $this

Tags: php, ruby, oop, this

What is the equivalent of PHP's `$this->` in Ruby?

Answer (score 20):

The ruby equivalent of `this` is `self` - they both refer to the current instance.

The tricky part is that in Ruby class scope, `self` refers to the current instance of the class `Class` that defines the class you are building.  Inside a method, `self` refers to the instance of the class.

eg:

```
class Example
  puts self  # => "Example" - the stringified class object

  def foo
    puts self  # #<Example:0xdeadbeef> - the stringified instance
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

The analog of `$this` is `self`, as has been mentioned. However, you asked about `$this->`, which means you want to use it to access an instance variable (`$this->somevar`) or instance method (`this->somemethod()`). For an instance variable, the equivalent in Ruby would be `@` (as in `@somevar`). For instance methods, the equivalent would be to just write the method name (`somemethod`), or, if you like to be verbose (`self.somemethod`).